# using math.random method to create dice method

Tags: java

ı basically created a program for a bet game and ı wanted to use math.random method to obtain possible face values.

my question is that math.random is always same value so ı cannot use it repeatedly.

how can ı use math.random method repeatedly. ı dont want to get same value for my dice;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab06d
{
  public static double money(double userMoney, int option, double bet )
  {
    //variable
    int dice1;
    int dice2;
    //codes
    dice1 = (int) Math.random() * 6 + 1;
    dice2 = (int) Math.random() * 6 + 1;
    System.out.println("dice sum: " + dice1 + dice2 );
    if(option == 1)
    {
      if((dice1 + dice2) % 2 == 1)
        userMoney = userMoney + ( bet / 2); 
      else
        userMoney = userMoney - ( bet / 4);
    }
    if(option == 2)
    {
      if((dice1 + dice2) % 2 == 1)
        userMoney = userMoney - ( bet / 4); 
      else
        userMoney = userMoney + ( bet / 2);
    }
    if(option == 3)
    {
      if((dice1 == 1 && dice1 == 1) || (dice1 == 6 && dice1 == 6))
        userMoney = userMoney + ( bet); 
      else
        userMoney = userMoney - ( bet);
    }
    return userMoney;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // variables
    double userMoney;
    int option;
    double bet;
    //codes
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


    System.out.println("enter your money: ");
    userMoney = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter your option 1 for odd 2 for even 3 for extreme: ");
    option = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter your bet: ");
    bet = scan.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(money(userMoney, option, bet));
    userMoney = money(userMoney, option, bet);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `Math.random()`, use a `Random` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(int) Math.random() * 6 + 1
```

means the same as

```
((int) Math.random())    *    6   +   1.
```

You're first rounding down, **then** multiplying and adding.
As Math.random() returns as number 0 <= x < 1, it is always casted to 0.
Notice that *(int)* always rounds down, so *(int) 3.999* would become 3 for example, as well as *(int)-3.9* would become -4.

Add braces like this:

```
 (int)     (Math.random() * 6 + 1)
```

You can also wrap it into a function like this:

```
static int throwDice() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
}
```

Operators in Java have a specific **precedence** to them, like multiplication comes before addition in mathematics, unless you use braces. You can look it up [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). When in doubt (or to clarify), use braces.

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer then by clicking the grey arrow left to it, so others can find it aswell.

Comment: of course it has time limit. after 2 min. ıll do it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the time of initializing dice 1, dice 2. You must remember that you can't pass a primitive type by reference to a method. So you must wrap the COMPLETE DATA, which in this case is Math.random()*6+1 and parse the integer type. So, the code would be

dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);